# errors when piping a specific find command and creating a zipfile from its output?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, zip, pipe

I wish to create a program that zips whatever file is created in the directory the find parameters specify, and run it as a background process. I heavily comment it to give a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm running this from my MacBook Pro terminal, OS X version 10.9

```
#!/bin/sh

#find file in directory listed below  
#type f to  omit  directories or special files  
#mtime/ctime is  modified/created  -0 days or less  
#name is with the name given in double quotes  
#asterik meaning any file name with any file extension  
#use xargs to convert find sequence to a command for the line after pipe  
find /Users/name/thisdirectory type f -ctime -0 -name "'*'.'*'" | xargs zip -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -ctime -0 -name "*.*" | zip -@ file.zip
```

If you read `zip -h`, it explains that `-@` is to read the filenames from standard input.

You don't need `xargs` here, the function to work with a list of files received from standard input is built into `zip` itself, similar to most compression tools like `tar`.

Btw, I think you want to change `-ctime -0`, because I don't think it can match anything this way...